# VTK ObbTree.IntersectWIthLine too slow for large-scale collision detection

Tags: python, gpu, vtk

I want to check the collision between a set of points to a point cloud (contain around 1M pts). I actually want to know which parts of the point cloud is collided with those outside points, and store those collided pts in the point cloud.

I loop through each outside point and use the Obbtree.IntersectWithLine to check the collision with each pt in point cloud, while it is too slow... I enabled the CPU parallel computing but the improvement is limited. I was wondering if any GPU-accelerated API that is compatible with the VTK objects, or there is a better-efficient way to check the collision?

Answer (score 0):

`IntersectWithLine` only intersects a segment to a polygonal mesh afaik.
You can maybe make a convex hull of the first cloud and then ask for the internal points of the second (?)

In this case one would use `vtkSelectEnclosedPoints`.